# There is no supported device - Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

This is my first app in Google store. When I began this project I set package name "example" automatically. After I tried to change package name but "refactor" didn't work(android studio). After I changed its name on gradle "example" to "bilgiyarisi" but changing seems in only gradle. Also it seems with new package name (bilgiyarisi) in store.

[image]

I think problem is about this. However I present manifest and gradle codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.korean"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity10" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity11" />
    <activity android:name=".SoruActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".mola" />
    <activity android:name=".Bilgi"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Here it is gradle..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bilgiyarisi.dell.korean"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

}

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

Now do I need to remove app from store? How I understand this problem is solved or not solved? Do I have to try upload apk continuosly when I change this codes, and will I wait 2-3 hours to see result? I dont know what i need to doing.

Comment: Can you get a friend to help you with the English in your post? Also, could you make an English version of your screenshot from the Google Play Developer Connection? If you do those two things, more people might be able to help you. :-)

Comment: english post is not necessary. just numbers are important in image

Comment: I don't know what a number means when its context is in Turkish.

Comment: the man who uploaded apk to google play before, understand this easily, by the way problem is solved. good luck